# Error 0x88 epson expression photo xp-750

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

I've a printer: epson expression photo xp-750. When i turn on it an error is displayed in screen of the printer. The error is 0x88.
Does anyone know what is the error 0x88 and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would sound like a defective encoder strip sensor, almost ANY copy repair shop can fix this for you, you can try to buy the manual and fix it your self but that is NOT recommended

Comment: What makes you say that in case of this particular printer model, error 0x88 corresponds to a defective encoder strip sensor? Can you provide a citation for that claim? What is the purpose of the encoder strip sensor in the printer? Please `edit` your answer to provide some more details on how this is the answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Correct! i bring the xp-750 to fix and they have changed the encoder strip sensor